# Can't Run a background PHP Script With Popen

Tags: php, background-process, popen, pclose

I have a PHP code that needs to run in background (no cronjobs or similar options) that is complete, but I just can't call it in the background. I'm trying the following:

```
$files = $_GET['files'];
$id = $_GET['id'];

pclose(popen("start /B D:\\server\\php\\php.exe D:\\server\\www\\whatever\\importat\\import.php?files=".$files."&id=".$id." 2>nul >nul", "r"));
```

But it' never runs. If I go and run ***import.php*** manually, it works without fail.

PS: I can't change the import.php.

Help?

Comment: Can't you just run the script in the web? E.g. `file_get_contents("http://www.link.to.script.com/import.php?params")`

Comment: Does the command works if you run it in cmd? Try turning on error report to see if it returns any errors.

Comment: @AndersAndersen I'm trying to run the script in this way `D:/server/php/php-win.exe "D:/path/to/progress_import.php?files=9&id=2"`, and I receive no errors in CMD, but it don't work either.

Using `file_get_contents`works, but don't runs in background, and that's the entire purpose of the script.

Comment: Using \ instead of / in the cmd don't change anything too.

Comment: @MetalSonic try looking, at first user contributed on this page http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php#86329 Its the one by "Arno van den Brink "  Maybe you need to remove this "2>nul >nul" in your command

Comment: Did it, but nothing happened. I've got permission and edited the *import.php* and make the code runs like this: `$cmd = "D:\\path\\php.exe D:\\path\\progress_import.php";
  pclose(popen("start /B ". $cmd, "a"));` But no success yet.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution:

What I am doing is calling the PHP inside a batch and launching it using popen:

```
$phpBatch = "progress_import_".$idImport.".bat";
$myPhp = fopen($phpBatch, "w") or die("Error opening file!");
$batchContent .= "@echo OFF \n";
$batchContent .= "\"D:\\path\\to\\php.exe\" D:\\path\\to\\progress_import.php ".$idImport." ".$_SESSION['numberFiles']." ";
pclose(popen("start /B D:\\path\\to\\".$phpBatch."", "r"));
```

And inside the `progress_import.php` i'm using:

```
$id = $argv[1];
$numberFiles = $argv[2];
```

To catch the parameters.

Hope that helps someone.